# Internal Server Error when i try to update dynamodb

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I have a problem updating data in dynamodb, when I send a request to my route to update patients it returns status 500 but I couldn't find out what is causing this error, I'm using express with serverless and api gateway

my controller

```js
import { Response, Request } from 'express';
import { updatePatientsService } from '../../services/patients/updatePatientsService';
import { getPatientsByIdSerive } from '../../services/patients/getPatientsByIdService';

const updatePatientsController = async (res: Response, req: Request) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    const { Item: patient } = await getPatientsByIdSerive(id);

    if (!patient) return res.status(404).send('patient not found');

    const newPatientUpdate = await updatePatientsService(req.body);

    return res.status(200).json(newPatientUpdate);
};

export { updatePatientsController };
```

my service

```js
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

import { Patient } from '../../types/interfaces/Patient';

const dynamoClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const tableName = process.env.PATIENTS_TABLE;

const updatePatientsService = async (patient: Patient) => {
    const params = {
        TableName: tableName!,
        Item: {
            ...patient,
        },
    };

    return await dynamoClient.put(params).promise();
};

export { updatePatientsService };
```

my routes

```js
import { Router } from 'express';
import { celebrate } from 'celebrate';

import { createPatientController } from '../../controllers/patients/createPatientController';
import { patientValidator } from '../../middlewares/validator';
import { getPatientsController } from '../../controllers/patients/getPatientsController';
import { getPatientsByIdController } from '../../controllers/patients/getPatientsByIdController';
import { updatePatientsController } from '../../controllers/patients/updatePatientsController';

const routes = Router();

routes.post('/', celebrate(patientValidator), createPatientController);
routes.get('/', getPatientsController);
routes.get('/:id', getPatientsByIdController);
routes.put('/:id', updatePatientsController);

export default routes;
```

Comment: 500 means an error occurred on the server and you need to view the server logs to see what the actual error is. It looks like you are using serverless, so your code running on AWS Lambda? If so the logs should be in CloudWatch Logs.

Answer (score 0):

A 500 exception from DynamoDB is an Internal Server Error in which something  happened on the DynamoDB side which is outside of your control. All of the AWS SDKs have built on retries which should retry the Update to completion.

It's important to understand that the 500 exception is being thrown by DynamoDB or another component of the stack. As a 500 from elsewhere could be a different issue which is inside of your control.

500s from DynamoDB are typically short lived and should not occur very often..

I would also suggest putting try/catch blocks on any API request you make to ensure you don't return exceptions downstream.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamodb-http-5xx-errors/

Comment: "message": "One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key id in the item",
    "code": "ValidationException", I got this error message in return, dynamodb needs to pass the id inside the Item to update?

Comment: I solved the problem, he needed me to inform the id inside the item object to save, I thought he would already get the id from inside the patient.

Comment: That looks like a better exception, which is 400. You must always provide the Partition key for any item write operation.